# MVC bulk upload for Arabic data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Im uploading excel file using sqlbulkupload

The file has Arabic data so it's inserted in the database like '??????' .

How can I solve this ? This is my code

```
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);

            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString);
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "StudentInfo";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer would be to convert your database columns to nvarchar types.  if they are varchar, they won't be able to hold unicode characters outside of the ascii range.

If they are already nvarchar in your database, try changing the connection string.  This example is from a vb6 app, but may be helpful:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=Unicode"""
```

Found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/34efad11-bf82-4484-9904-107c3c39a302/reading-from-a-csv-or-a-txt-file-in-unicode-format

Comment: They are already nvarchar and it's collation is Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS

Comment: @Mariam, I updated it to try changing your flat file (ole) connection string to specify unicode.